# bash command splitting up giving errors

Tags: bash

I am having an issue here trying to create a bash script for rclone

This give me an error:

```
20d: command not found
```

```
DAYS='20d'
PURGE='purge --min-age' ${DAYS}
rclone ${PURGE} ${DEST}/old/ $VERBOSE $LOGS
```

This works

```
PURGE='purge --min-age 20d'
rclone ${PURGE} ${DEST}/old/ $VERBOSE $LOGS
```

Can someone help me out here so I can use the first one? It makes it so much easier for others to use this script if all they have to do is change DAYS

Comment: You're not really telling what you're trying to do, but if those are meant to be arguments to `rclone`, then see [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373), and [the relevant parts of the answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/170373)

Answer (score 2):

Your quoting for the `PURGE` variable is causing this.

Currently you are setting:

```
PURGE='purge --min-age'
```

And then **executing** `${DAYS}` (20d) with the `PURGE` variable in its environment.

You probably want:

```
purge=(purge --min-age "$days")
```

(Arrays are a much safer way to hold command line arguments than unquoted variables)

You would call it like:

```
rclone "${purge[@]}" "${dest}/old" "$verbose" "$logs"
```

Note: You should only use uppercase variable names for environment variables.

---

Take the following example:

```
$ FOO=bar env | grep FOO
FOO=bar
$ env | grep FOO
$
```

We are setting the `FOO` variable to `bar` and then executing the `env` command with this variable in its environment.

You are getting an error because `20d` isn't a valid command.

Comment: It's even more likely that they want `purge=( purge --min-age "$days" ); rclone "${purge[@]}" "$dest" ...`  as to not have to _rely_ on the field splitting of the shell to split the arguments in `$purge` correctly.

Comment: ok, so if I use the format you recommend "${purge[@]}" how will that work with adding the rest of the info I want to the purge command? How does it get the 'purge --min-age 20d' part into the command?

Comment: It gets that part from `${purge[@]}`.  Your request for clarification isn't clear

Comment: ok. The way I do it now based on the help I got
`days='20d'`
`purge=(purge --min-age "$days")`
Then I use `rclone $purge` to rclone command and it give me this output  `purge --min-age 20d`
If I use `${purge[@]}` will everything after = in `purge=(purge --min-age "$days")` be added were the @ is?

So if I want to do the same in this example it will be like this?
`ignorefile=".rclone-ignore"
exifpresent=('--exclude-if-present' ${ignorefile})
rcolne sync / "${dest}/recent" --backup-dir "${dest}/old/${date}" "${exitifpresent[@]}"`